# Bookown' bibliography multiple languages

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, bibliography

I need to put two reference sections. References are equal, but in first section it must be in russian and in english in the second section (see png example). What shall I do to create bibliography references in multiple languages with R+Bookdown+Zotero/Juris-M?
[image]

Comment: What is the intended output format? HTML, PDF, ...?

Comment: Similar question for LaTeX/PDF: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358254/duplicate-bibliography-references-in-two-languages. It might be possible to adjust this for usage with `bookdown`.

Comment: Good day. Output format is *docx :-( I would like to make the format independent documents as possible. Thanks for nice LaTeX example.

Comment: Ok, docx is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Perhaps, do you know how include your LaTeX solution in rmarkdown? It might work.

Comment: One possibility would be to alter the used template. It will take a few days before I have time for that.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution for LaTeX/PDF output.

- I started with a clone of [bookdown-start](https://github.com/seankross/bookdown-start)
- In `index.Rmd` and `_output.yml` I removed the bibliography specific things
- In `index.Rmd` I defined a main font with Cyrillic characters
- In `_output.yml` I specified a `after_body` include for the bibliography
- I added the LaTeX code from [LaTeX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358254/duplicate-bibliography-references-in-two-languages) to `01-Introduction.Rmd`, `preamble.tex` and `biblio.tex` as well as the two `*.bib` files

Here the relevant git diff:

```
diff --git a/01-Introduction.Rmd b/01-Introduction.Rmd
index b94150e..372258d 100644
--- a/01-Introduction.Rmd
+++ b/01-Introduction.Rmd
@@ -2,3 +2,12 @@

 This is the first real chapter.

+Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
+eiusmod \mycite{book1} tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
+aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
+laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
+in reprehenderit \mycite{book1, article1} in voluptate velit esse
+cillum \mycite{article1} dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
+occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
+mollit anim id est laborum.
+
diff --git a/_output.yml b/_output.yml
index 112cf5b..a04dcf9 100644
--- a/_output.yml
+++ b/_output.yml
@@ -11,7 +11,8 @@ bookdown::gitbook:
 bookdown::pdf_book:
   includes:
     in_header: preamble.tex
+    after_body: biblio.tex
   latex_engine: xelatex
-  citation_package: natbib
+  keep_tex: yes
 bookdown::epub_book:
   stylesheet: style.css
diff --git a/biblio.tex b/biblio.tex
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ea1eab8
--- /dev/null
+++ b/biblio.tex
@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@
+\chapter{Combined References}
+\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
+\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{Список литературы}}
+\bibliography{biblio_ru}{}
+\bibliographystyleen{ugost2008}
+\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}}
+\bibliographyen{biblio_en}{}
diff --git a/index.Rmd b/index.Rmd
index ece36fe..e3bba35 100644
--- a/index.Rmd
+++ b/index.Rmd
@@ -4,8 +4,7 @@ author: "Sean Kross"
 date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
 site: bookdown::bookdown_site
 documentclass: book
-bibliography: [book.bib]
-biblio-style: apalike
+mainfont: Noto Serif
 link-citations: yes
 github-repo: seankross/bookdown-start
 url: 'http\://seankross.com/bookdown-start/'
diff --git a/preamble.tex b/preamble.tex
index dfd2e14..c522818 100644
--- a/preamble.tex
+++ b/preamble.tex
@@ -1 +1,8 @@
 \usepackage{booktabs}
+
+\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
+\newcites{en}{english}
+\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1}\nociteen{#1}}
+
+\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
+\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.\hfill}
```

Unfortunately when I use `build book`, the second bibliography is ignored, brobably because `bibtex` is not called on the additional `en.aux` file. I used to be able to configure RStudio to use `latexmk` via setting `RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX`, but this is no longer working for me. Workaround:

- Use `keep_tex: yes`
- Copy the `*.bib` files to the output directories
- manually call `latexmk -xelatex ...` in the output directory

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [multiple-bibliographies.lua](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/multiple-bibliographies/multiple-bibliographies.lua) filter. Currently I used in linux with success, having installed:

```
sudo apt install pandoc-citeproc
```

In your bookdown folder (you can test cloning [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo)), modify your index.Rmd:

```
--- 
title: "book title"
author: "name name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
always_allow_html: true
output: 
   bookdown::word_document2:
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua

bibliography_english: [eng.bib]
bibliography_russian: [rus.bib]

documentclass: book
csl: yourCslFileForFormattingCitesOptional.csl
link-citations: yes
description: "text"
---
```

At the final chapter, add:

```
# English references {-}

::: {#refs_english}
:::

# Russian references {-}

::: {#refs_russian}
:::
```

Note: this will produce an html, but also a .docx in the folder _book.