# Specifing a `.bst` file in `biblio-style` does not work when knitting `bookdown::pdf_document2`

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, citations, bibliography

I'd like to customize the citation style when I knit an `.Rmd` file with  `bookdown::pdf_document2` option, specifing `biblio-style` in its YAML section. 
I saw that using `.csl` file rather than `.bst` has solved some former questions about formatting citation sections in `bookdown`
(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596158/how-to-change-to-another-bibliography-style-in-bookdown/50610720#50610720) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown/49145699#49145699)).
However, in my case, I have to specify which `.bst` file to use in `biblio-style` line in the YAML of `.Rmd` because there is no `.csl` file which satisfies my citation style...

I'm trying to use [jecon-unicode.bst](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode.bst) to produce my citation sections (I changed the file name as `jeconunicode.bst` in my working directory due to the error with the hyphen in the file name). By this file, I can cite the documents published in English in APA style and, simultaneously, I can also cite the documents written in Japanese following the style which some academic societies in Japan recommend. I intend to make the citation sections as shown below:

### Desirable Result

#### In-text Citation

> Suzuki and Tanaka (2032)
>
> 鈴木・田中 (2021)

As you can see, "・" separates the multiple author names in in-text citations when a document written in Japanese language.

#### Reference Section

> Suzuki, Ichiro, and Taro Tanaka (2032) “Our First Investigation: This
>   Is Not the First, but This Should Be the Last.” *Journal of Something*
>   Vol.23, No. 5, pp. 19–176.
>
> 鈴木一郎・田中太郎 (2021) 「われらの発見について：変貌を遂げつつある何とかの将来に関する過去・現在・未来」, 『何十華論考』, 第42巻, 第5号, 128–82頁.

In the reference section, [jeconunicode.bst](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode.bst) will also treat Japanese and English document differently, without creating different reference sections per language (i.e. the reference chapter I want to create is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866392/bookown-bibliography-multiple-languages/50905522#50905522)). For instance, in the same bibliography section, 「」『』 are uesd for Japanese document names, while " " and italicization are used to modify English document names.

In order to activate [jeconunicode.bst](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode.bst), I wrote `Test.Rmd`, inserting `myref.bib` in it.

### Test.Rmd

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y年 %B %d日')`"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: TRUE
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: TRUE
    fig_caption: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
    extra_dependencies: subfig
    citation_package: natbib
link-citations: yes    
always_allow_html: yes
documentclass: ltjsarticle
header-includes:
   - \RequirePackage{luatexja}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.PNG}
   # You can unset Japanese font specification
   # - \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
   # - \setmainjfont{YuMincho}[UprightFont=YuMincho-Regular,BoldFont=YuMincho-Demibold]
   # - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
   # - \setsansjfont{YuGothic-Medium}[BoldFont=YuGothic-Bold]
   # - \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
   - \setlength\parskip{0mm}
   - \setlength\parindent{1\Cwd}
   - \usepackage[japanese]{babel}
   - \captionsjapanese
   - \newdimen\bibindent
   - \setlength\bibindent{3\Cwd}
bibliography: myref.bib
biblio-style: jconunicode.bst
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# 何とかの考察に関する歴史

@ST-jp は、「なんとかとは何とかだ！」[@ST-jp]と述べた。
しかし、@ST-en では一転して、
「Something should be more significant than something!!」[@ST-en]と
主張している。



# 参考文献 {-}

\leftskip=3\Cwd

\setlength\parindent{-3\Cwd}

<div id="refs"></div>

\leftskip=0pt

\setlength\parindent{1\Cwd}
```

### myref.bib

To make [jeconunicode.bst](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode.bst) recognize which article is written in Japanese, it is necessary to add `language = {Ja}`.

```
@article{ST-jp,
title = {われらの発見について：変貌を遂げつつある何とかの将来に関する過去・現在・未来},
journal = {何十華論考},
volume = 42,
number = 5,
pages = {128 -- 182},
year = {2021},
author = {鈴木, 一郎 and 田中, 太郎},
language = {ja}
}

@article{ST-en,
title = {Our first investigation: this is not the first, but this should be the last},
journal = {Journal of Something},
volume = 23,
number = 5,
pages = {19 -- 176},
year = 2032,
author = {Suzuki, Ichiro and Tanaka, Taro}
}
```

However, I got only the undesirable result for the present. [jeconunicode.bst](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode.bst) specified in the `biblio-style` option doesn't have any effect on the output and the default citation style is used, although I put `.Rmd`, `.bst`, and `.bib` files in the same directory.

### Current Unwanted Result

#### In-text Citation

> Suzuki and Tanaka (2032)
>
> 鈴木 and 田中 (2021)

#### Reference Section

> Suzuki, Ichiro, and Taro Tanaka. 2032. “Our First Investigation: This
>   Is Not the First, but This Should Be the Last.” *Journal of Something*
>   23 (5): 19–176.
>
> 鈴木, 一郎, and 田中太郎 . 2021. “われらの発見について：変貌を遂げつつある何とかの将来に関する過去・現在・未来.” **何十華論考** 42 (5): 128–82.

Is there any nice way to cite Japanese and English (or any languages with Latin alphabet) in harmony as I pointed out above?

### My Session Info

I use the bookdown in RStudio as shown below, with TeXLive 2018, under Windows 10:

```
>devtools::session_info(('bookdown'))
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.453)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Japanese_Japan.932          
 tz       Asia/Tokyo                  
 date     2018-08-30                  

Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 bookdown    0.7     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 graphics  * 3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 grDevices * 3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 methods   * 3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 Rcpp        0.12.18 2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 rmarkdown   1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 stats     * 3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 stringi     1.1.6   2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 stringr     1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 tinytex     0.6     2018-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 tools       3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 utils     * 3.4.3   2017-12-06 local         
 xfun        0.3     2018-07-06 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 yaml        2.1.16  2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Comment: That YAML header should read `biblio-style: jeconunicode`, i.e. without `.bst` and with an `e`. Unfortunately your document does not compile on my system, so I cannot say if that is a solution (missing fonts).

Comment: @RalfStubner
Thank you for your fast reply. I edited the original post: I fixed the typo you pointed out and deleted the Japanese font specification section. I hope now you can try to compile the document without Japanese fonts (i.e. `YuMincho` and `YuGothic-Medium`).

Comment: @RalfStubner

When I set `natbib` in `citation_package`, the file fails to compile. However, when I add `- \usepackage{natbib}` right after `\usepackage[japanese]{babel}` to configure the package loading order
 (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283232/problem-with-natbib-and-french-babel-after-migrating-to-el-capitan#comment683013_283232)),
instead of touching `citation_package`, I do get an `pdf` output but the result is not desirable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your issue with the following test file:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y年 %B %d日')`"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: TRUE
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: TRUE
    fig_caption: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
    extra_dependencies: subfig
    citation_package: natbib
link-citations: yes    
always_allow_html: yes
documentclass: ltjsarticle
header-includes:
   - \RequirePackage{luatexja}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.PNG}
   - \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
   - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
   - \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
   - \setlength\parskip{0mm}
   - \setlength\parindent{1\Cwd}
   - \usepackage[japanese]{babel}
   - \captionsjapanese
   - \newdimen\bibindent
   - \setlength\bibindent{3\Cwd}
bibliography: myref.bib
biblio-style: jeconunicode
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# 何とかの考察に関する歴史

@ST-jp は、「なんとかとは何とかだ！」[@ST-jp]と述べた。
しかし、@ST-en では一転して、
「Something should be more significant than something!!」[@ST-en]と
主張している。


# 参考文献 {-}

\leftskip=3\Cwd

\setlength\parindent{-3\Cwd}

<div id="refs"></div>

\leftskip=0pt

\setlength\parindent{1\Cwd}
```

Instead of producing the undesired output, my HD was filled with several GB of error messages from `bibtex`. Among many others there was:

```
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1643 of file jeconunicode.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1644 of file jeconunicode.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1645 of file jeconunicode.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1646 of file jeconunicode.bst
```

I figured that I should be using the `pbibtex` instead of `bibtex`. Indeed, processing the resulting `tex` and `aux` files manually with `pbibtex` and `lualatex` worked fine. Since I found no way to configure that, I just created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/pbibtex ~/bin/bibtex
```

This way a call to `bibtex` would actually call `pbibtex`. 
After that the document compiled, even though it took several calls to "Knit" within RStudio to get the references resolved:

[image]

To me this looks like the desired output. I cannot explain why you are seeing different results.

```
> devtools::session_info(('bookdown'))
Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio (1.2.830)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  de_DE.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2018-08-31                  

Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source                         
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 bookdown    0.7     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 digest      0.6.16  2018-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 evaluate    0.11    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 glue        1.3.0   2018-08-24 Github (tidyverse/glue@4e74901)
 graphics  * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 grDevices * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 highr       0.7     2018-06-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 methods   * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 Rcpp        0.12.18 2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 rmarkdown   1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 stats     * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 stringi     1.2.4   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 stringr     1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
 tinytex     0.8     2018-08-30 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 tools       3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 utils     * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                          
 xfun        0.3     2018-07-06 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
 yaml        2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Comment: You got the right result. I got your idea that you made a symbolic link from `pbibtex` on your user's home directory so that `knitr` uses `pbibtex`. However, your solution doesn't work straightforwardly in my environment, because my OS is Windows 10 (and that's why we got the different results, in my view). I tried to create a soft link from `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\pbibtex.exe` but I'm not sure where to locate such a symbolic link, because in my home directory, there is no `bin`. If Windows is available, could you show me the way to use `pbibtex` when knitting a document?

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera The link has to be in a directory that is in your `PATH` and before the other version. If that does not work you can try it to reprocess the produced `tex` file with `lualatex` and `pbibtex`.

Comment: Your second solution works nicely. After I press `ctrl` + `shift` + `k` to knit the document, the execution doesn't complete (i.e. R Markdown tab in RStudio doesn't return `Output created: test.pdf`) however long it takes. Nontheless, I find `test.tex` and related files (e.g. `test.log`, `test.bbl`, and so on) exist in my directory. So, I reprocess `test.tex` with `upBibTeX` once and with `LuaLaTex` twice. I used `upBibTeX` 'cause [The official document of jeconunicode](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/jecon-bst/blob/master/unicode/jecon-unicode-xelatex.pdf) recommends us using it.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera Great. I have added the manual processing to the answer. Feel free to accept/up-vote it as you see fit.

Comment: Although your 2nd solution satisfies me a lot, still I have to do some TeXing. Speaking of the 1st one, it seems that the `PATH` from `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32` has already set before I encountered the problem. Therefore, RStudio seems to have an access to `(u)pbibtex` already, no matter RStudio really does access it. To complete producing a document solely with RStudio, what do you think I should do? I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73760/169454) and I think `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")` has to do with solving this issue, though my trial doesn't go well so far...

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera Does `latexmk` work when called directly? Then you can try setting `RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX`. I am not sure if that still works. You might have to configure `tinytex` instead.

Comment: Yes, `latexmk` itself works when I call on the shell (in my environment, `Windows PowerShell`), though I needed to configure `.latexmkrc` in my home dir. I set the file as shown below: `#!/usr/bin/env perl $latex = 'uplatex %O -kanji=utf8 -no-guess-input-enc -synctex=1 %S'; $lualatex = 'lualatex %O -synctex=1 %S'; $bibtex = 'upbibtex %O %B'; $makeindex = 'upmendex %O -o %D %S'; $pdf_mode = 4; $pdf_previewer = '"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\sumatra\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance';`. Yet, `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")` written in `.Rprofile` still has no effect.

Comment: @RulfStubner I do have `tinytex` package but I haven't tried `install_tinytex()` because I've already have the broader TeX system called `TeX Live 2018`. Although `latexmk` command (i.e. `latexmk test2`) on the shell goes well with the setting specified in `.latexmkrc` above, executing `latexmk("test2.tex")` on the console of RStudio fails to compile the document.

Comment: @RulfStubner Following [this guideline to use `TeX Live` rather than `TinyTeX`](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/48#issuecomment-407015282), I executed `options(tinytex.latexmk.emulation = FALSE)` but in vain.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera This sounds as if `tinytex::latexmk` is ignoring your configuration file. To test this, you can make the file syntactically incorrect so that `latexmk` raises an error when called in the shell. Does this error also happen with `tinytex::latexmk` (without emulation)?

Comment: @RulfStubner Sorry, which file shoud I intentionally add bad syntax to? To `.tex` file?

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera The configuration file `.latexmkrc`.

Comment: @RulfStubner I'm sure `tinytex::latexmk` ignores `.latexmkrc` in the home dir. I began a new R session and executed `options(tinytex.latexmk.emulation = FALSE)` only on the console, commenting `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")` and `options(tinytex.engine = 'lualatex')` out. Then `Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...` came up and the document compilation failed. If `tinytex::latexmk` accessed `.latexmkrc`, `test2.tex` should've been processed by `LuaLaTeX` without `options(tinytex.engine = 'lualatex')`.

Comment: @RulfStubner Adding some multibite characters into `.latexmkrc` was "incorrectly" ignored when I typed `tinytex::latexmk("test2.tex")` on the R console, i.e. `pdflatex` was called as if there were no error in `.latexmkrc`. However, the bad perl syntax "rightly" caused the malfunction when I used the shell: `Latexmk: Initialization file 'C:/Users/My name/.latexmkrc' gave an error`. After I deleted the characters, the shell command `latexmk test2` produced the output. However,`tinytex::latexmk("test2.tex")` on the R console behaved same even after the deletion of the characters.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera It worked for me when I used your `.latexmkrc`. Maybe `latexmk` does not find the file when called from R. What's the value of the environment variables `HOME` and `USERPROFILE` in R and in the shell. You could also copy the configuration file to the working directory.

Comment: As `USERPROFILE` which both R and PowerShell (PS, henceforth) showed is identical, I only configured `HOME`. On Windows in general, the default `HOME` for R is `C:/Users/MY NAME/Documents`, so I changed it as `C:/Users/MY NAME` so that R's `HOME` can be the same as PS's one. However, `tinytex::latexmk("test2.tex")` still calls `pdflatex`. Even `tinytex::latexmk("test2.tex", engine = "lualatex", emulation = FALSE)` doesn't work for creating PDF output. I'm sure that I've executed `options(tinytex.latexmk.emulation = FALSE)`. Moreover, `.latexmkrc` in my working dir has no effect.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera I am out of ideas. I think it is best if you open an issue in the `tinytex` repository on GitHub referencing this question for further context.

Comment: I entirely appreciate your supports. I've learned many ways to configure R and TeX through the discussion with you. I will tell you if I find further information and ideas to solve this issue.